# What house were James and his friends in?

Tags: harry-potter, sorting-hat

I have (as I believe most people do) always believed that James, Lily, Sirius, Lupin and Peter were all in Gryffindor house.

However I've never found any canon to support this. I half expected us to discover in Hallows that they were in fact in Slytherin!

- James and his friends were often considered arrogant and frequently bullied Snape
- Peter was anything but heroic!

Is there any canon stating which houses the previous generation were in?

Comment: The Sorting Hat is never wrong.  And we see later that Peter does indeed have some bravery in him.

Comment: The question of Pettigrew in Gryffindor has been discussed here before: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7514/why-was-peter-pettigrew-sorted-to-gryffindor

Comment: Isn't it also mentioned in Philosipher's Stone that Harry finds a quiditch trophy with is father's name on it stating he played for Gryffindor?

Comment: Serius Black was a Gryffindor, the black sheep of the family.

Comment: Well, considering how J.K. Rowling writes, it's very safe to assume that any major back story character was either in Gryffindor or Slytherin. She sorta tends to forget that she has two other houses in the story a lot.

Comment: @Mallow The "black" sheep. HAHHAAH!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In *Deathly Hallows*, we witness Snape’s memory of his Sorting (and he was in the same year as them). We see Lily and the four Marauders all sorted into Gryffindor:

> Then Professor McGonagall said, “Evans, Lily!”
>
> He watched his mother walk forward on trembling legs and sit down upon the rickety stool. Professor McGonagall dropped the Sorting Hat onto her head, and barely a second after it had touched the dark red hair, the hat cried, “Gryffindor!”
>
> […]
>
> The roll call continued. Harry watched Lupin, Pettigrew, and his father join Lily and Sirius at the Gryffindor table.

Alternatively, somebody else asked this exact same question in a [2004 interview with JKR](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2004/0304-wbd.htm):

> What houses were Sirius Black, Remus Lupin, James Potter and Remus Lupin[sic] in? Everyone tells me they were all Gryffindor, but I won't believe it unless I hear it from Ms. Rowling herself!
>
> **JKR:** This is JK herself saying that they were indeed in Gryffindor!

Yep, the Marauders were in Gryffindor.

(I’m assuming the second mention of Lupin was meant to be Pettigrew.)